# Change platform style for alert in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have set the following in ionicBootstrap

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp,[],{
    mode: 'md',
    alertEnter: "alert-pop-in",
    spinner: 'ios'
});
```

I would like to know how to change the platform style to ios just for the alerts. I was able to change the spinner to ios but I wasn't able to find a way to change the alert style to ios in https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/ section: Default Mode Configuration